# Sqlite Prepare Failed: No such table <table_name>

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am using Sqlite database in my iphone app.

Here in my app i initially used a absolute path like @"/Users/macos/Documents/appdatabase.sql

Now here I want to run the app on the device. It requires the relative path.

What needs to be done to get that path for the database ?

Here I am getting this error when i try to run with the absolute path on the device.

Sqlite Prepare Failed: No such table

I have checked that  table already exist in my database.

What should I do to get the relative path for the database?

Please Help and Suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the database path using this -

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydb.sqlite"];
```

also delete your app from simulator or device and run/install it again.

Comment: You will need to call `[databasePath stringByExpandingTildeInPath]` before you use it